# Bash stdin - I'm losing all newline characters

Tags: bash, gnupg

I have this bash script to do encryption:

```
#!/bin/bash
#encrypt.sh

fn=$1
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Filename required..."
fi

echo "Type text. Hit Ctrl-d when done"
keyvariable=$(cat)

echo -e $keyvariable | gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 > $fn
```

And I have this script to do decryption:

```
#!/bin/bash
#decrypt.sh

fn=$1
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Filename required..."
fi

cat $fn | gpg --decrypt
```

Example:

`sh encrypt.sh test`

```
Type text. Hit Ctrl-d when done
hello

how

are




you

?
```

I enter the password and confirm it. OK great. I now have an encrypted file called "test".

But when I go to decrypt "test", here's the output:

`sh decrypt test`

```
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
-e hello how are you ?
```

I'm losing all the newline characters! What to do?

---

Answer is quite simple actually:

`echo -e "$keyvariable" | gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 > $fn`

Note the quotes around $keyvariable.

That's it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line

```
echo -e $keyvariable | gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 > $fn
```

when `$keyvariable` is expanded, any embedded *whitespace* (not just newlines) are used to split the resulting string into a number of distinct words. `echo` then outputs each word to standard output, separated by a single space. Newlines are just the most obvious "victims"; you might observe tabs (0x09) being replaced by spaces, as well as multiple runs of whitespace being reduced to a single space. There are other characters that may change as well, due to filename generation (the details of which are unimportant here).

The solution is to quote the parameter expansion:

```
echo -e "$keyvariable" | gpg --symmetric -cipher-algo AES256 > "$fn"
```

As others have mentioned, it's simpler to allow `gpg` to read from standard input directly, instead of using `cat` to intercept the keystrokes and placing them in a variable.

```
echo "Type text. Hit Ctrl-d when done"
gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 > "$fn"
```

(Actually, `gpg` may behave slightly differently when it is reading directly from the terminal, as shown here, versus reading from a pipe, as when you read from the `echo` command. That could explain your being prompted   for a password. I *think* the solution is to tell `gpg` to read from standard input specifically by adding "-" as a final argument, but consult your man page to verify. That is,

```
gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 - > "$fn"
```

)

Comment: It works perfectly with the quotes! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Eamorr: It's great that it works with the quotes, but really the last part of chepner's solution is the best one, where you avoid storing the input at all, and just let gpg take stdin directly.  Consider using it.

Comment: Hey, that solution works on the command line, but it doesn't prompt for input within a script.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store it in a variable and then echo the variable into gpg. Pipe it through. In your setup, you should just send the output of `cat` through the gpg call without needing the echo.

Or do without the `cat` altogether! Delete the line where you store the input, and delete the echo part, so that line just reads

```
gpg --symmetric ...
```

Comment: Hi, so I deleted the echo. All I get is `Type text. Hit Ctrl-d when done"` and then `Enter passphrase: `. I don't get an opportunity to enter any text!

Answer (score 1):

The question is not about gpg, but about bash and echo. You are missing quotes. Check this script and see the difference.

```
s=$(printf "one\ntwo")
echo $s
echo "$s"
```